# Accessing and changing texture data in SlimDX

Tags: textures, directx11, slimdx

How can I access and change texture data in SlimDX?  I have a Texture2D and a Texture3D and I need to be able to go in and change either a single or group of pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to update textures once in awhile (e.g. while loading a new level), you can do it with [UpdateSubresource](http://slimdx.org/docs/html/M_SlimDX_Direct3D11_DeviceContext_UpdateSubresource_1.htm).  However, **beware** that this can cause a CPU-GPU sync point, which will trash your performance if you're doing it every frame.

If you need to update textures in real-time, a better way is to bind it as a render target and draw on it with a shader that performs the required alterations.

Comment: What if I want to change just a single or few pixels in a 3D texture?  What's the fastest way to go about that?

Comment: @jacker I haven't worked with 3D textures much, but I think you have to update each depth slice separately, as a 2D texture.

Comment: Ok well with a 2d texture then?

Comment: @jacker For a 2D texture it's like I said in the answer...is there something you need clarification on?